# Adding trailing slash to URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to re-write my URL using htaccess. Here is the code from my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)?/([^/.]+)?$
post.php?pst=$1&view=$2%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Everything is working fine, except that this code doesn't add a trailing slash at the end of the re-written URL. How can I add that?

Comment: Did you mean to have a slash after the {QUERY_STRING}?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access `%{QUERY_STRING}` in a RewriteRule; only a RewriteCondition. I think you might need to do something like:

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)?/([^/.]+)?$ post.php?pst=$1&view=$2%1/
```

See: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString